# NOT_FOUND - no queue 'node-topic-queue-one' in vhost '/'

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have Made a simple app that send message to the client via RabbitMQ server.
For that I have created sender side code as below.

```
var amqp=require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost',login:'guest',password:'guest'});

connection.on('ready', function () {
 // There is no need to declare type, 'topic' is the default:

 var exchange = connection.exchange('node-topic-exchange'); 

 console.log("publishing messages");
 exchange.publish("topic_a.subtopic_a", {msg:'First Message'});
 exchange.publish("topic_a.subtopic_b", {msg:'Second Message'});
 exchange.publish("topic_b.subtopic_b", {msg:'Third Message'});
 });

 connection.on('error',function (err) {
  console.log('an error '+err);
 });
```

and my receiver side code is as shown below:

```
var amqp=require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost',login:'guest',password:'guest'}); 
 connection.on('ready', function () {
  // There is no need to declare type, 'topic' is the default:
  var exchange = connection.exchange('node-topic-exchange');
  // Consumer:
  var queue = connection.queue('node-topic-queue-one');
  queue.bind(exchange, "topic_a.*");
  queue.subscribe(function (message) {
  // Get original message string:
  console.log('Message : ' + message.msg);
   });
  });
  connection.on('error',function (err) {
 console.log('an error '+err);
});
```

problem is that..it gives an error like that

> D:\node example\RabbitMQ Example>node worker1.js an error
>
> Error:
>   NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'node-topic-exchange' in vhost '/' an error
>   Error: read ECONNRESET

please help to solve this out.....

Comment: I guess that you need to use node.js event driven approach: "An exchange will emit the 'open' event when it is finally declared." (https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#connectionexchangename-options-opencallback) - the exchange is not declared yet when you try to use it.

Comment: It works,,!! but also I got same error in receiver side...@Sigismondo

Comment: same story there, and for the queue as well! With other languages (eg java) you need to explicitly "declare" exchanges and queues (that is, create if not exist) and for good decoupling its good practise to do it on both producers and consumers.

Comment: added the answer too, so others can find it useful

Comment: Thanks..it Works... :) @Sigismondo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use node.js event driven approach: ["An exchange will emit the 'open' event when it is finally declared."](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#connectionexchangename-options-opencallback) - the exchange is not declared yet when you try to use it.

On the receiver side you need to do the same for the exchange and for the queue: ["A queue will call the callback given to the connection.queue() method once it is usable"](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#queue)

For completeness I report the example here:

```
var q = connection.queue('my-queue', function (queue) {
  console.log('Queue ' + queue.name + ' is open');
});
```